# How to specify user-permission in Ionic source code

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

So far, what I did: I modified `platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml` file manually (in Ionic project) and added this two lines, but this file and whole platforms folder are not under source control. As a result, with each clean checkout, these permissions are missing.

Is there a way to specify these two permissions somewhere in Ionic configuration that is in git?

Comment: If you're using Ionic Native plugins, the permissions will be added automatically by Ionic into your config.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following lines in **config.xml**

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

Can Refer below link 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/camera/camera.html

Comment: Does not work with Ionic 3 and Cordova 6. Also I don't have cordova plugin installed as I don't need it (I use getUserMedia API)

Comment: So you need permission for audio or photo? You can have another option https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/